# Creating HashMap with a timeout.Will Guava Caching work?

Tags: java, servlets, dictionary, guava

This is my HashMap.

```
Map<String,MyObject> mymap=new HashMap<String,MyObject>();
```

I want to perform normal operation like get and put and I want one more operation i.e **the map automatically removes an object when the object is not accessed for more than a certain time**

Is it Similar to Google Guava?If yes,please give an example.And as far as I read Guava doenot support put.

If no,is there a way to do this?

EDIT:Whenever I get a GET request from the user I create  myobject and store it in the map.And if I get the another request from the user having the same Key I get the stored object from the user,do some operation and again store it back.

If the key is a new key then the map should return a null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See javadoc on guava's CacheBuilder (it contains examples):

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html

Also this: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained

**UPDATE**:  It is not necessary to use a cache loader, or to have a load method.  This test case passes:

```
@Test
public void testManualInsertion() {

    Cache<String, String> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(1000)
            .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .removalListener(new MyRemovalListener())
            .concurrencyLevel(4)
            .recordStats()
            .build();


    cache.put("someKey", "someValue");

    assertEquals("someValue", cache.getIfPresent("someKey"));

}
```

Comment: :Please look at the edit. Does Guava support 'put'. I couldnot find it anywhere.And should my load method return null?

Comment: I implemented the above but I got a java class not found error com.google.common.cache.Cache .Do you have any idea why is it for?Its compiling perfectly.Trouble at runtime

Comment: Make sure you have the same version of guava at runtime as you do at compile time.  CacheBuidler and Cache were added within the last few versions.

Comment: I am using guava 14.01 and its present only in project/JavaResources/lib/guava.jar . Do we need two jar files?Where should I put the second one?Here is how my eclipse project folder looks like.[link To the project Image](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_pKO9JFqkPsX042OEN1ZnVDa1U/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Nope, there is just one jar, and 14.0.1 definitely contains com.google.common.cache.Cache.  So that error message at run-time just means your run-time classpath is not correctly including the guava jar.